# Google Cloud Speech recognition captures also played audio in device

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I am trying to recognize user voice with Cloud speech recognition, and I send it to ChatGPT after I got response, I am playing it with media player, but speech recognition recognizes also played audio voice. I don't want to pause recognition because while audio playing, I want speech recognition to be able to capture user speech. How can I differentiate played audio voice and user speech or how can I prevent speech recognition capturing played audio?